# Flutter Image Package Updates

Tags: flutter, image, dart

The changelog on the `image` package is pretty vague, and I am going through my code to update to the most recent version, but I am having trouble understanding what is what now. Two functions in particular I am having trouble migrating to the newest version and they are the old `drawImage` function and the `copyInto` function. For example

```
//this took in two images, and overlayed the first one of the second one
//Draw the image src onto the image dst.

drawImage(Img1, Img2)

//Copies a rectangular portion of one image to another image. dst is the destination image, src is the source image identifier. 
//In other words, copyInto will take an rectangular area from src of width srcw and height srch at position (srcx,srcy) and place it in a rectangular area of dst of width dstw and height dsth at position (dstx,dsty).

copyInto(Img1, Img2, dstY: int, dst: int, blend: true)
```

I believe `drawImage` is now `compositeImage`, but it isn't clear. I cannot find a direct replacement of `copyInto` in the newest docs. Is there one?

Comment: I've just read that drawImage and copyInto have been merged into the same function https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/blob/main/doc/draw.md#compositeimage

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
compositeImage(fullMergeImage, image, dstY: pos);
```